# Symfony3 - The association refers to the owning side field which does not exist with ManyToMany and fields table

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, relation, symfony3.x

i'm trying to make a manyToMany relationship with more attributes than the ids, so I need two OneToMany relationships and two ManytoOne relationships having three tables/entities.

I have Product entity, Client entity and ProductClient entity:

```
class Client 
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_client", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idClient;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \ProductClient
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductClient", mappedBy="client")
     */
    private $products_clients;

}

class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_product", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idProduct;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \ProductClient
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductClient", mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $products_clients;
}

class ProductClient
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="product_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="products_clients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id_product", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="client_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="products_clients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id_client", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="boolean")
     */
    private $status;
}
```

That's something like this (with its getters and setters and more attributes). But symfony launches two "invalid entities errors" when I go to the Product crud:

> AppBundle\Entity\Product - The association AppBundle\Entity\Product#products_clients refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\ProductClient#product which is not defined as association, but as field.
>
> AppBundle\Entity\Product - The association AppBundle\Entity\Product#products_clients refers to the owning side field AppBundle\Entity\ProductClient#product which does not exist.

And the same result if I go to the Client crud. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the error message, `AppBundle\Entity\ProductClient#product is not defined as association, but as field`.

Just remove this `@ORM\Column(name="product_id", type="integer")` and this `@ORM\Column(name="client_id", type="integer")`.

```
class ProductClient
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="products_clients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id_product", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="products_clients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id_client", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="boolean")
     */
    private $status;
}
```

Comment: But with this two lines i'm defying the name of fields in mysql. I don't have to do it? This table in mysql have a product_id  and client_id flelds.

Comment: @Manuel González Burgueño, You've already defined the names of these fields by annotations `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="something")`, so you don't need `@Column`